# MS Excel + VBA: setting data label orientation programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, charts, label

I'm trying to set the orientation of data labels on a bar chart to vertical.  Normally I'd find out how to do this by recording a macro, but for some reason it doesn't seem to generate any code.  Is it possible to do?

I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what recording the macro generated:

```
With Selection.TickLabels
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .Orientation = xlDownward
End With
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think that's the axis labelling.  Anyway, after a bit of further rooting around on MSDN I've found it:

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Orientation = 90

Comment: Ohh I thought you were looking for the axis labelling, my bad!